# Font-size changed after adding proxy

Tags: .net, angular, proxy, reverse-proxy, font-size

I have got website on virtual machine in my company. Site backend was created with .Net Core & fronted was created with Angular2. 
 This site can be accessed by link like: 
 https://192.168.1.243:9090/website/ 
And we add proxy to company server that connects our services with the internet.
 
 After you access:  
https://company.com/website/ 
 you can access site that is pushed to virtual machine.
Everything works great, except font-size on tables where i display data from backend.
Data is received by api calls in angular2 and angular2 part gets json responses.

So now when i access site by virtual machine address everything seems good.

But when i try to connect by our company address font-size of this tables is changed (body declares 14px, this tables got 16px font-size).

Maybe somebody have idea what can be reason?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason might be that with proxy, your are not able to retrieve a CSS file.
From google chrome, open the Developer console (f12) and check any 404 errors in the console.